# Laravel API routes not found in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I am using Laravel 8, and my application is hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. All the routes (routes/web) work fine, but the routes in API (routes/api) show NOT FOUND. The routes API is working ok in the localhost, which is the problem in Elastic beanstalk or EC2 where it is hosted that does not let access to these API routes. Does anyone have any solution? The server's in Apache, pointing out /public.

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show your `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: @PunyFlash  Hello, good morning. I added inside the publication now. Tks

Comment: Going to be silly to ask this but happens when you try to hit the end point? Error? 404? Going to state the obvious here too...  If you access endpoint in browser you are hitting it like http(s)://mydomain.com/api/dosomething?

Comment: I'm not sure, all seem to be fine. May that be, that you forgot to cache that routes on AWS after adding them? (`php artisan optimize`)

Comment: @JustJeremy hello, good morning. The laravel show me Error 404 Not Found, i'm acessing with Postman int the route mydomain.com/api/Users

Comment: Often times this is due to a caching problem, especially if you've changed routing. I would do like many others have said and clear all your caches.  In my mind the only thing preventing this from working in prod is bad routing.  If it works in dev but not prod it's almost always has to do with cache. Do not run all the commands you posted.  That will for sure mess things up. Especially generating a new key!

Answer (score 1):

run the commands:

```
>> php artisan auth:clear-resets
>> php artisan cache:clear
>> php artisan config:clear
>> php artisan event:clear
>> php artisan optimize:clear
>> php artisan route:cache
>> php artisan view:clear
>> php artisan config:clear                            
>> php artisan view:clear                              
>> npm run dev                                         
>> php artisan key:generate 
>> php artisan optimize
```